# I got the tiles of a raster and I would like to create the original raster

Tags: raster, tiles

I got the tiles of a map named

`txt
2x0x0.png
2x0x1.png
...
2x1x1.png
2x1x2.png
...
2x45x1.png
2x45x2.png`

The first part is the zoom, the second the row and the las the column number.

Is it possible to produce the original raster file?

Comment: Which software are you planning to use? The keyword you're looking for is "mosaic", there should be plenty of answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I used [php](http://www.php.net) and [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) with the following code

```
<?php
if (!array_key_exists(1,$argv)) {
   echo 'arg 1 - Path is required'.PHP_EOL;
   exit();
}
if (!array_key_exists(2,$argv)) {
   echo 'arg 2 - Zoom is required'.PHP_EOL;
   exit();
}
$prevRow = null;
$cols = array();
$rows = array();
$files = (glob($argv[1].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$argv[2].'*'));
usort($files,function($a,$b) {
   $filenameA =  pathinfo($a, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $filePartsA = explode("x",$filenameA);

   $filenameB =  pathinfo($b, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $filePartsB = explode("x",$filenameB);

   if (intval($filePartsA[1])<intval($filePartsB[1])) return -1;
   if (intval($filePartsA[1])>intval($filePartsB[1])) return 1;
   if (intval($filePartsA[2])<intval($filePartsB[2])) return -1;
   if (intval($filePartsA[2])>intval($filePartsB[2])) return 1;
   return 0;
});
foreach($files as $file) {
   $fileExtension =  pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $fileName =  pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $fileParts = explode('x',$fileName);
   $row = $fileParts[1];
   $col = $fileParts[2];
   if (!is_null($prevRow) && $prevRow != $row) {
       $fileRow = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$row.'.'.$fileExtension;
       $rows[]=$fileRow;
       $cmd = 'convert "'.implode('" "',$cols).'" +append '.$fileRow;
       $result = exec($cmd);
       echo 'Generate row '.$row;
       if ($result != '') {
          echo $result;
       }
       echo PHP_EOL;
       $cols = array();
   }
   $cols[]=__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
   $prevRow = $row;
}
echo 'Generate global file ';
$cmd = 'convert "'.implode('" "',$rows).'" -append '.__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'out.'.$fileExtension;
$result = exec($cmd);
if ($result != '') {
    echo $result;
 }
```